# VBox Guest not filling entire screen on start-up

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 18.1 as a guest using VirtualBox.

I've done this about 5 times now trying to see what's causing the issue, but because I'm not that well endorsed in these kind of things, I just couldn't possibly figure out where to look.

The issue I'm having is that whenever I boot up the VM, the machine arrives to the logon screen in a chopped up scale ratio (i.e. borders). Only once I logon OR reboot will the issue fix itself.

The issue I have with this is that it's inconsistent. It can obviously load at full-screen at all times as it does when I reboot, but it doesn't do so when initially booting up. Even if the issue is only present at the start/logon screen, this is annoying.

I don't understand what's throwing off the machine, but I've had it.

Call me OCD, but this is driving me nuts. I didn't have this issue with my 17.3 VM, but VBox has gone through some updates since then.

I installed the G.A. using VB, and I have enough video memory allocated to the machine. I also have 3D acceleration enabled. If I didn't, I'd be getting a warning for software rendering mode.

I've gone through the process of posting on both related forums, but I have not received sufficient feedback.

All I need is a point in the right direction. Where I can look to find out what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely normal for most hypervisors softwares (  used Oracle virtual box some time ago and now currently with Hyper V)

What happens is that initially during startup the hypervisor uses its graphics default  drivers which usually do not amount to full resolution, but after loading BIOS it then detects those drivers you added for the particular virtual machine and adjusts the resolution according to the settings you have saved in Display properties, so I doubt if there is really a workaround for that (my hypervisor acts just like that)

Maybe configuring the Hypervisor to prevent them initially load their default drivers?? But I'm you might need to approach the software developers for that.